# When does ng-class ends expression evaluation and applies the class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-class

I'm trying to reach something similar to a FullScreen-mode feature: using a button to trigger the fullscreen mode, then another button to return.

The subject:

```
 <div ng-class="{full: !presentationMode}"> 
     <div id="child-div>content</div> //div has 100% height
 </div>
```

The trigger:
    `<button ng-click="present()">Click me!</button>`

And in the controller I do:

```
$scope.present = () => {
            $scope.presentationMode = !$scope.presentationMode;
            var myDiv = angular.element('#container');

            // when $scope.presentationMode is true
            // myDiv.height() is not the height set by the "full" class, but it is always reversed (the previous value) 

            // It !sometimes! work if I use $timeout.
 }
```

How should I handle this situation?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29641/

Answer (score 2):

You got a syntax:

`<div ng-class="{full: !presentationMode}">`

You should have your class name in ' '

`<div ng-class="{'full': !presentationMode}">`

Comment: Doesn't help. It doesn't matter if the class name does not contain a dash!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems that there was a scope digest cycle problem: I was trying to access the div's height before the class was applied, so that's why I always got the previous (height) value.

The solution is to get div's height inside the $timeout's function, with no delay, but with invokeApply set on false (the default is true).

```
$timeout(function() {
    console.log(myDiv.height()); //has correct value
}, 0, false);
```